# How to cascade two filters?

Tags: matlab, audio, convolution, finite-impulse-response

I have to filter an audio signal through a cascade of two equal low-pass FIR filters. They are half-band filters so each one has a cut-off at $\pi/2$.

Then, I have to multiply the resulting signal (obtained through the cascade of the two filters) for $z^{-q}$, where $q$ is a scalar.

Firstly, I thought to convolve the impulse responses of the two low-pass filters in this way  (where `hlp1=hlp2`):

```
hconv=conv(hlp1, hlp2),
```

and then filter the audio signal (called `x`) in this way:

```
x_filtered=filter(hconv,1,x)
```

Is it correct?

I expect that the frequency response `hconv` is a low-pass filter with cutoff at $\pi/4$, but the command `fvtool(hconv)` shows that `hconv` has a cutoff at $\pi/2$, and not at $\pi/4$.

Is it correct?

Moreover, how can I implement the multiplication of the filtered signal `x_filtered` for $z^{-q}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily verify yourself that the following two ways of cascading two filters are equivalent (up to numerical inaccuracies):

```
% method 1
y1 = filter(h1,1,x);
y = filter(h2,1,y1);

% method 2
h = conv(h1,h2);
y = filter(h,1,x);
```

So you were on the right track when you convolved the two impulse responses. Note that *linear* convolution is what you need, not circular/cyclic convolution.

As for the multiplication with $z^{-q}$, where I hope that $q$ is an integer, you need to understand that it is not the (time-domain) signal that is being multiplied, but that this multiplication refers to the Z-transform of the signal. In the Z-transform domain, a multiplication with $z^{-q}$ corresponds to a delay of $q$ samples.

Finally, regarding your expectation that the cut-off frequency of the cascaded system is $\pi/4$, note that the frequency response of the cascaded system is simply the multiplication of the two individual frequency responses, so the cut-off frequency does not change significantly (it may change a bit depending on how you define it). The transition from pass band to stop band will be steeper, and the stop band attenuation increases, but the start of the transition band remains unchanged. If both filters are identical you will basically get a better low pass filter with the same pass band and stop band edges.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I understand that the cut-off frequency of the cascade of two halfband low-pass filters is still pi/2 . My aim is to filter the audio signal through a cascade of two halfband filters (hlp1 and hlp2), where hlp1 takes a half of the spectrum (so, from 0 to pi/2), and hlp2 takes a half of the output spectrum of hlp1 (so from 0 to pi/4 ). How can I do that with two halfband filters? What parameter I have to change in the second halfband filter  (hlp2) to reach my goal?

Comment: also now that i think about it, multiplying by $z^{-q}$ you could create your own FIR kernel. If $q < N$, for filter length $N$, create `delay=zeros(N,1); delay(q)=1; y = filter(delay,1,cascadeOutput)`

Comment: @rainbow: You could decimate the signal by a factor of 2 after applying the first half-band filter, then filter it with the second half-band filter.

Comment: @panthyon: Regarding your delay filter, you'd need to write `delay(q+1)=1` (think about the case $q=1$ to see it).

Comment: ah yes, MATLAB indexing

Comment: @rainbow: Also note that the passband peak-peak ripple of your equivalent cascaded filter will be twice as large as the passband peak-peak ripple of either of the two identical cascaded filters.

Comment: @panthyon: Thank for your comment, very useful!
But why "delay" is a coloumn vector, and not a row vector? With the "filter" function I always use row vectors.

Comment: @Matt L.: Thank you! 

Silly question: Which test signal "x" could I use in the code below to see and better understand that the cascade cuts at $\pi/4$?


y1 = filter(h1,1,x);

y1_dec=decimate(y1, 2);

y = filter(h2,1,y1_dec);

Comment: @Richard Lyons: Thanks for the detail! I'll verify that, even if it's not important for my case, because I haven't any requirement on ripples.

Comment: @rainbow rows by cols or cols by rows, it doesn't matter as long as it's one-dimensional

Comment: @rainbow: $\pi/4$ is a normalized frequency. After the second filter you'll see that the cut-off is at $\pi/2$, but that's relative to the reduced sampling rate, so it is $\pi/4$ relative to the original sampling rate. Example: if the original sampling rate is 48 kHz, then the first half-band filter will reduce the signal's bandwidth to 12 kHz. After down-sampling and half-band filtering, the signal has a bandwidth of 6 kHz, which corresponds to $\pi/4$ relative to the original sampling rate of 48 kHz.

Comment: @Matt L.: I think that in the example above, the sampling rate should be 24 kHz (and not 48 kHz). In this way, the signal's bandwidth after the first halband filtering will be reduced to $12 kHz$, and the signal bandwidth of the output signal will be reduced to 6 kHz. Am I right?

Comment: @rainbow: No, with a sampling rate of 24 kHz, your maximum signal bandwidth is 12 kHz (check the sampling theorem), so a half-band filter would reduce this maximum bandwidth by half, which amounts to 6 kHz.

Comment: Yes, you're rigth. Sorry for the mistake. Thank you!